# How to calculate units with range value of numbers

Tags: google-sheets

**We sell greeting cards and this is how it works**

**Scenario 1:**

1. if you want to send 1 greeting card up to 10 cities then the price will be 15USD
2. if you want to send 1 greeting card up to 25 cities then the price will be 40USD
3. if you want to send 1 greeting card up to 50 cities then the price will be 90USD
   *the price will increase if cities are over 10 but equal to 25 or less*

**Scenario 2:**

1. if you want to send 2 greeting cards upto 10 cities then the price will be 25USD
2. if you want to send 3 greeting cards upto 25 cities then the price will be 50USD
   *the price will calculate based on 2 greeting cards cities equal to 25 or less*

[Here is the Google Sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lwxjDAf4h2JB9KKK-_19FiYIng8T_swAAlVfTMAhhVI/edit?usp=sharing), I am trying to work on but I totally lost it, cannot figure it out at all.

Comment: In your post and in your sheet, you say this: "if you want to send 3 greeting cards up to 25 cities then the price will be 50USD." But this seems wrong to me. Should it be "if you want to send 2 greeting cards up to 25 cities..."?

Comment: it could be 1,2,3,4,5,6 or any number of greetings to any number of cities. 
basically, the price of 1 greeting to send up to 10 cities in one price then changes if you increase the number of greeting cards or a number of cities.

greeting card prices change with each increasing number where city price is 1-10 one price, then 11-25 one price and so on...

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. Based on your post, sending 1 card to 10 cities is $15. Sending 2 cards to 10 cities is $25, which denotes a discount (i.e., without the discount 2 cards to 10 cities would be 2 x $15 = $30). So how much would 3 cards to 10 cities be? How much for 3 cards to 20 cities? 5 cards to 20 cities? I don't see a pattern.

Comment: All alright, my mistake I will explain with simple figures, with every additional 10 cities price increases 60% and every number of cards add up the same amount which is %15 per card so the 1 card with 10 cities $15 
2 card 10cities - only card price increases 
1 card 20 cities - 60% increases as first 10 cities are free
does that make sense now?
btw, your question made me restructure the prices as well, thanks for that too.

Comment: Nope. Still not making sense. On your second sheet, you write "if you want to send 1 greeting card up to 50 cities then the price will be 90USD." Yet in your first sheet, "Shipment 5," you have 1 card going to 50 cities and the total price is $15. I think it will be best for you to manually enter 10 or 15 different combinations of # of cards, # of cities and total price, along with explanations for every line about how you the calculation was made. Please be SURE your figures are accurate, as every time I check this and try to understand, it requires real time.

Comment: I think instructions on the sheet making confusion but as i wrote above, i restructured the prices after you raised questions so if you ignore instructions on the sheet and read just above comment, maybe then it will make sense?

Comment: I'm afraid it does not make any more sense when ignoring your sheet. Keep in mind that you know what your end goal is very well; but we "out here" don't know what you know. Sometimes, when we know something very well ourselves, we tend to explain it as if everyone else should understand it as clearly as we do. Again, the best way to explain is to show a number of specific examples with explanations as I described above. This post has had many comments and is still not solved. I fear that moderators will soon lock the sheet due to lack of clear explanation. So please do add the examples soon.